# Lengthy sub-menu list items break functionality of CSS nav menu

Tags: html, css, menu

**Probably easiest to just start here and look at the fiddles:**

Menu with desired behavior: [Correct Example](http://jsfiddle.net/o1rtdxms/3/)

Menu with broken behavior due to lengthy sub-item: [Broken Example](http://jsfiddle.net/o1rtdxms/2/)

---

```
I'll explain this as best I can....
```

I have a side-menu with list items that can contain a second-level menu with its own respective items.

When mousing over the main-menu, the sub-menus appear next to their parent item. The problem occurs when one of the sub-menus have an item with a long amount of text. This makes the following main-menu item's "unreachable", in that you can't just keep going down to click them. You have to mouse out of the sub-menu, then mouse directly to the main-item you want.

The goal here is to have a working multi-level side-menu written only in CSS and HTML.

Comment: What browser are you using? because it is working correctly for me.

Comment: I see what you are talking about now.

Comment: Did you try playing around with the z-index?

Comment: @AhsN You are correct, I added an answer with an example for James.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your submenu is sitting on top of the other list items because you haven't positioned the submenu properly.

```
#main_menu li ul{
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    left:100%;
    top:0;
}
```

No need to position the submenu `li` at all.

Try this:

```css
ul{
    list-style:none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#main_menu{
    width:150px;
}

#main_menu a{
    display:block;
}

#main_menu a:hover {
    background:red;
}

#main_menu li:hover > ul{
    display:block;
}
#main_menu li ul{
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    left:100%;
    top:0;
}

#main_menu li{
    position:relative;
}

#main_menu li ul li{
    white-space:nowrap;
}



/* just for styling purposes */
#main_menu a{
    width:100%;
    background:#66CCFF;
    text-align:center;
    border:solid black 1px;
}
#main_menu a[href='#']{
    font-weight:bold;
}
#main_menu a[href='#']:after{
    content: "\203A";
    float:right;
}
#main_menu li ul li a{
    background:#CCFFFF
}
```

```html
<ul id="main_menu">
    <li>
        <a href='#'>Item A</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href='javascript: return false'>A.1</a></li>
            <li><a href='javascript: return false'>A.2</a></li>
            <li><a href='javascript: return false'>A.3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href='#'>Item B</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href='javascript: return false'>B.1</a></li>
            <li><a href='javascript: return false'>B.2</a></li>
            <li><a href='javascript: return false'>B.3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href='#'>Item C</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href='javascript: return false'>C.1</a></li>
            <li><a href='javascript: return false'>C.2</a></li>
            <li><a href='javascript: return false'>Long Sub-element Causes Problem</a></li>
            <li><a href='javascript: return false'>C.4</a></li>
            <li><a href='javascript: return false'>C.5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href='javascript: return false'>Now reachable</a></li>
    <li><a href='javascript: return false'>Now reachable</a></li>
```

Comment: Yes! Hard-coding those position properties definitely felt wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Ahs in the comments, the `z-index` will fix it like this http://jsfiddle.net/o1rtdxms/5/

```
ul{
    list-style:none;
}
#main_menu{
    width:150px;
}

#main_menu a{
    display:block;
}

#main_menu li:hover > ul{
    display:inline;
     z-index: -1000;
}
#main_menu li ul{
    position:absolute;
    display:none;

}
#main_menu li ul li{
    position:relative;
    top:-20px;
    left:112px;

}
```

Comment: It does fix it partially. You can reach the 'unreachable' links now but, now the problem is that you cannot hover on the sub-menus.

Comment: @AhsN you're correct...any idea on how to accomplish both?

Answer (score -1):

Your Fiddles both work exactly the same for me.

If you want to do this in pure HTML/CSS (on your end), it'd be easier to use a framework like Bootstrap (they do the JS for you, you just use classes, which limits it to HTML/CSS, as you requested).

You should try it on different browsers to see what works and what doesn't, and the browser that doesn't work should lead you to ask some more questions cross-browser-compatible related.

Comment: They "both" do not work the same, and your "answer" should go in the comments section.